# Python разработка web-приложений

Tags: python, веб-программирование, apache-modules, apache

Добрый день, мне предстоит написать сайт на Python-e, предполагается, что это будет что-то типа картографического сервиса, пользователь будет заполнять форму, после этого формируется запрос, исходя из которого формируется карта. Нужно заметить, что формирование карты будет довольно таки ресурсоёмким.

Сайт изначально будет написан просто на Python-е, потом планируется прикрутить туда Django.

Теперь сам вопрос: что лучше использовать для запуска python-программ, посредством браузера? Веб-сервер - Apache.

- CGI, FastCGI
- mod_python
- mod_wsgi

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Причины использования Apache нынче должны быть достаточно вескими. Функционал Apache обычно не нужен для современных веб-сайтов, создаваемых с Python. А память жрать Apache будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше не использовать Apache. Практически все фреймворки идут со своим веб сервером, для локального запуска этого более чем достаточно. Для показа в мир также апач не нужен — достаточно nginx.

В любом случае, если без апача никуда, то только WSGI интерфейсы.

Comment: А вообще по быстродействию и производительности nginx вроде же лучше чем Apache? Как-то я думал, что nginx в большинстве случаев для работы со статикой устанавливают.

Comment: @rumato Быстрее и легче, здесь он фактически выступает как прокси к WSGI, выполняя минимальную работу.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, буду разбираться.

Comment: У django встроенный web сервер принимает исключительно одни запрос в одну единицу времени, другими словами для тестов он самое то, но не для продакшина.

Comment: sonniy, так и разработчики Django от этом пишут, там примерно написано "не вздумайте использовать встроенный сервер в реальных проектах"

Answer (score 2):

Я счтаю, что `nginx wsgi`  если из внешних, а так можно попробовать что-нибудь из питоньих веб-серверов или фреймворков, `gunicorn`, `tornado`, `twisted` и так далее.

Answer (score 2):

"Сайт изначально будет написан просто на Python-е, потом планируется прикрутить туда Django.".

Это в корне не верная формулировка. Не "прикрутить Джангу", а "заново разработать сайт на Джанге". Кстати, почему Джангу? Для вашей задачи не самый идеальный фреймворк, как мне представляется.

Запуск Питона для целей отладки осуществляется с помощью запуска интерпретатора Python. Не браузером. Программа на Питоне запускается отдельно, начинает слушать порт 80, к которому, в свою очередь, подключается браузер.

Если не для целей отладки, то это уже зависит от конкретного админа и конкретного веб-приложения. Например, можно nginx + uwsgi, чаще всего используется, имхо. Но я сейчас от него отошел и использую nginx + supervisord.

По сути можно и без всего этого - достаточно как угодно запустить программу на Питоне как службу Винды или демона Юниха. И все.

Как правило, все веб-фреймворки предлагают свои варианты запуска. Желательно только разгрузить веб-приложение от обработки статики, что я и делаю через nginx

Comment: Я всё приложение, так делаю чтобы потом в случае чего можно было используя Django всё переписать, там у меня самая главная часть это работа в данными, конвертирование и т.д. А по nginx + supervisord можете пояснить чем такая связка Вас привлекает?

Comment: У меня вируальные сервера. Хостер из соображений безопасности ограничил на уровне ядра межпроцессные взаимодействия. И он прав.


В результате приходится запускать несколько экзепляров uwsgi - каждый под свое веб-приложение. В частности - реализовывать в настройках ОС отдельного демона под веб-приложение.


А в режиме "императора" (с централизованным управлением uwsgi несколькими веб-приложениями) - не стартует свежая версия uwsgi, ругается на то самое межпроцессорное взаимодействие, которое отключил хостер. Очень старая версия uwsgi работает, но не стабильно.


Поэтому перешли на supervisord

Comment: Простите, что значит "в случае чего использовать Django" ?

Плюс Django - быстрая разработка веб-приложений. Переписывание "в случае чего" сайта на Django выглядит противоречием к основному плюсу Django - к экономии времени при разработке.

Comment: Главное в моём творении это обработчик данных, программа запускается обрабатывает довольно большие объёмы данных, полученных со спутника, потом отрисовывает карту, собственно весь интерфейс пока сводится к форме запроса и самой карты. Потом когда с обработкой более-менее будет ясно, тогда уже можно писать полноценный сайт куда встроить уже сделанные модули.

Comment: Я так и не понял из вашего объяснения, а зачем, собственно, Django? Даже когда это все будет до ума доводиться. Зачем именно такой фреймворк?